# Why does my PIVOT query produce NULL results with a dataset that contains no NULLs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a device database, which contains data on devices, including names, locations, and a number of numeric and string attributes. I am trying to execute a query, pulling only those attributes with numeric values into a pivot table.

When I query the data flatly, the data looks fine. But when I run the `PIVOT` query on the same dataset, all results are `NULL`.

**Setup:**

```sql
/* database setup and data insert */

USE [master] ;
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = N'DeviceDatabase' )
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [DeviceDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;
    DROP DATABASE [DeviceDatabase] ;
END
CREATE DATABASE [DeviceDatabase] ;
GO

USE [DeviceDatabase] ;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Devices
(
    [id]                        INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1,1)
        CONSTRAINT      [PK_Devices]            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [device_name]             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    , [device_display_name]     VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    , [device_location]         VARCHAR(50)     NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE dbo.DeviceGroups
(
    [id]                        INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1,1)
        CONSTRAINT      [PK_DeviceGroups]       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [device_group_name]       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE dbo.DeviceDeviceGroups
(
    [id]                        INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1,1)
        CONSTRAINT      [PK_DeviceDeviceGroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [device_id]               INT             NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT      [FK_DeviceDeviceGroups_Devices]
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Devices ( [id] )
    , [group_id]                INT             NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT      [FK_DeviceDeviceGroups_DeviceGroups]
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.DeviceGroups ( [id] )
) ;

CREATE TABLE dbo.DeviceAttributes
(
    [id]                        INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1,1)
        CONSTRAINT      [PK_DeviceAttributes]   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [device_id]               INT             NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT      [FK_DeviceAttributes_Devices]
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Devices ( [id] )
    , [attribute_name]          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    , [attribute_value]         VARCHAR(50)     NULL
) ;
GO

INSERT
    INTO        dbo.Devices
                ( [device_name], [device_display_name], [device_location] )
    VALUES      ( 'dev001', 'Device 1', 'Location A' )
                , ( 'dev002', 'Device 2', 'Location A' )
                , ( 'dev003', 'Device 3', 'Location B' )
                , ( 'dev004', 'Device 4', 'Location B' ) ;

INSERT
    INTO        dbo.DeviceGroups
                ( [device_group_name] )
    VALUES      ( 'Group 1A' )  
                , ( 'Group 1B' ) ;

INSERT
    INTO        dbo.DeviceDeviceGroups
                ( [device_id], [group_id] )
    VALUES      ( 1, 1 )
                , ( 2, 1 )
                , ( 3, 1 )
                , ( 4, 1 ) ;

INSERT
    INTO        dbo.DeviceAttributes
                ( [device_id], [attribute_name], [attribute_value] )
    VALUES      ( 1, 'attrib #1', '0.10' )
                , ( 1, 'attrib #2', '0.02' )
                , ( 1, 'attrib #3', '0.07' )
                , ( 1, 'attrib #4', '0.02' )
                , ( 2, 'attrib #1', '0.16' )
                , ( 2, 'attrib #2', '0.05' )
                , ( 2, 'attrib #3', '0.12' )
                , ( 2, 'attrib #4', '0.04' )
                , ( 3, 'attrib #1', '0.15' )
                , ( 3, 'attrib #2', '0.05' )
                , ( 3, 'attrib #3', '0.07' )
                , ( 3, 'attrib #4', '0.06' )
                , ( 4, 'attrib #1', '0.10' )
                , ( 4, 'attrib #2', '0.03' )
                , ( 4, 'attrib #3', '0.07' )
                , ( 4, 'attrib #4', '0.03' ) ;
GO
```

It is annoying the that `attribute_value` column is a string rather than numeric, but not all attributes are numeric in nature. (And this is the vendor's schema.)

When I execute a flat query (with CTEs) against the table I get a full set of attribute values.

**Query:**

```sql
/* flat query */

USE [DeviceDatabase] ;
GO

DECLARE     @PrinterGroup   AS VARCHAR(50) ;
SET         @PrinterGroup   = 'Group 1A' ;

WITH cte_GroupedDevices AS
(
    SELECT          d.[id] AS [device_id]
                    , d.[device_name]
                    , d.[device_display_name]
                    , d.[device_location]
                    , dg.[device_group_name]
    FROM            dbo.Devices AS d
        INNER JOIN  dbo.DeviceDeviceGroups AS ddg
            ON      d.[id] = ddg.[device_id]
        INNER JOIN  dbo.DeviceGroups AS dg
            ON      ddg.[group_id] = dg.[id]
    WHERE           dg.[device_group_name] = @PrinterGroup
)
, cte_AttributedDevices AS
(
    SELECT          gd.[device_name]
                    , gd.[device_display_name]
                    , gd.[device_group_name]
                    , gd.[device_location]
                    , da.[attribute_name]                   
                    , CAST ( da.[attribute_value] AS DECIMAL (5,2) ) AS [attribute_value]
    FROM            cte_GroupedDevices AS gd
        INNER JOIN  dbo.DeviceAttributes AS da
            ON      gd.[device_id] = da.[device_id]
    WHERE           da.[attribute_name] IN
                    ( 
                        'attrib #1'
                        , 'attrib #2'
                        , 'attrib #3'
                        , 'attrib #4'
                    )
)
SELECT          [device_display_name]
                , [device_group_name]
                , [device_location]
                , [attribute_name]                  
                , [attribute_value]
FROM            cte_AttributedDevices
ORDER BY        [device_name] ASC, [attribute_name] ASC ;
```

**Result:**

```
device_display_name  |  device_group_name | device_location  |  attribute_name   |  attribute_value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 1                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #1           0.10
Device 1                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #2           0.02
Device 1                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #3           0.07
Device 1                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #4           0.02
Device 2                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #1           0.16
Device 2                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #2           0.05
Device 2                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #3           0.12
Device 2                Group 1A            Location A          attrib #4           0.04
Device 3                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #1           0.15
Device 3                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #2           0.05
Device 3                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #3           0.07
Device 3                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #4           0.06
Device 4                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #1           0.10
Device 4                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #2           0.03
Device 4                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #3           0.07
Device 4                Group 1A            Location B          attrib #4           0.03
```

But when I execute a `PIVOT` query (pivoting the `attribute_name` column), with the same CTE base, against the same dataset, all attribute values are NULLed.

**Query:**

```sql
/* pivot query */

USE [DeviceDatabase] ;
GO

DECLARE     @PrinterGroup   AS VARCHAR(50) ;
SET         @PrinterGroup   = 'Group 1A' ;

WITH cte_GroupedDevices AS
(
    SELECT          d.[id] AS [device_id]
                    , d.[device_name]
                    , d.[device_display_name]
                    , d.[device_location]
                    , dg.[device_group_name]
    FROM            dbo.Devices AS d
        INNER JOIN  dbo.DeviceDeviceGroups AS ddg
            ON      d.[id] = ddg.[device_id]
        INNER JOIN  dbo.DeviceGroups AS dg
            ON      ddg.[group_id] = dg.[id]
    WHERE           dg.[device_group_name] = @PrinterGroup
)
, cte_AttributedDevices AS
(
    SELECT          gd.[device_name]
                    , gd.[device_display_name]
                    , gd.[device_group_name]
                    , gd.[device_location]
                    , da.[attribute_name]                   
                    , CAST ( da.[attribute_value] AS DECIMAL (5,2) ) AS [attribute_value]
    FROM            cte_GroupedDevices AS gd
        INNER JOIN  dbo.DeviceAttributes AS da
            ON      gd.[device_id] = da.[device_id]
    WHERE           da.[attribute_name] IN
                    ( 
                        'attrib #1'
                        , 'attrib #2'
                        , 'attrib #3'
                        , 'attrib #4'
                    )
)
SELECT          [device_display_name]
                , [device_group_name]
                , [device_location]
                , [attrib_1]
                , [attrib_2]
                , [attrib_3]
                , [attrib_4]
FROM            cte_AttributedDevices
PIVOT
(
    MIN ( [attribute_value] )
    FOR [attribute_name] IN
    (
        [attrib_1]
        , [attrib_2]
        , [attrib_3]
        , [attrib_4]
    )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY        [device_name] ASC ;
```

**Result:**

```
device_display_name  |  device_group_name | device_location  |  attrib_1  | attrib_2 |  attrib_3  | attrib_4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 1                Group 1A            Location A          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Device 2                Group 1A            Location A          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Device 3                Group 1A            Location B          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Device 4                Group 1A            Location B          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I have tried a number of different functions in the `PIVOT` segment of the query -- `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG` -- all of which produce the same result.

I have tried dumping the data into a temp table -- one with a numeric data type on the `attribute_value` column -- but it produces the same result, both with the flat and the pivoted query.

And I have tried a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `attribute_value` column, both in the base table and on the temp table. Again with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see, in your PIVOT, you refer to [attrib_1] (for example) when it seems like you should use [attrib #1]

Comment: This is one of the problems with pivot - because the columns it produces are sourced from column data *values*, there's no metadata for the server to be able to tell you up front "you spelled that wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example.  Note:  @YourResults is a substitute for your actual initial query.

I don't see any logic where you transform `attrib #1` to `attrib_1`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourResults Table ([device_display_name] varchar(50),[device_group_name] varchar(50),[device_location] varchar(50),[attribute_name] varchar(50),[attribute_value] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourResults Values 
 ('Device 1','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #1',0.10)
,('Device 1','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #2',0.02)
,('Device 1','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #3',0.07)
,('Device 1','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #4',0.02)
,('Device 2','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #1',0.16)
,('Device 2','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #2',0.05)
,('Device 2','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #3',0.12)
,('Device 2','Group 1A','Location A','attrib #4',0.04)
,('Device 3','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #1',0.15)
,('Device 3','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #2',0.05)
,('Device 3','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #3',0.07)
,('Device 3','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #4',0.06)
,('Device 4','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #1',0.10)
,('Device 4','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #2',0.03)
,('Device 4','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #3',0.07)
,('Device 4','Group 1A','Location B','attrib #4',0.03)
 
Select * 
 From @YourResults
 Pivot (min([attribute_value]) for [attribute_name] IN (
                                                         [attrib #1]
                                                       , [attrib #2]
                                                       , [attrib #3]
                                                       , [attrib #4]
                                                       ) ) Pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

**EDIT - If you want [attrib_1]** You can specify the columns and assign the alias.

```
Select [device_display_name]
      ,[device_group_name]
      ,[device_location]
      ,[attrib_1] = [attrib #1]
      ,[attrib_2] = [attrib #2]
      ,[attrib_3] = [attrib #3]
      ,[attrib_4] = [attrib #4]
 From @YourResults
 Pivot (min([attribute_value]) for [attribute_name] IN (
                                                         [attrib #1]
                                                       , [attrib #2]
                                                       , [attrib #3]
                                                       , [attrib #4]
                                                       ) ) Pvt
```

[image]